# Ожидание загрузки данных на страницу asp net

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp

Дорого времени суток. Делаю проект интернет-магазина на asp .net 7
Возник вопрос: как сделать ожидание загрузки, например, товаров на страницу?
Т.е. чтобы статические элементы по типу хедера футера и т.д. сразу отобразились на странице, а товары показались только тогда, когда будут получены данные из бд, загрузятся картинки товара и т.д.
А пока идет загрузка данных, вместо товаров отображается кружочек загрузки.
В базе данных хранится название картинки или путь, а сами картинки хранятся в папке на сервере приложения.

Comment: `<img loading="lazy"`

Comment: Спасибо! Все оказалось очень просто 